# Playing all videos in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-media-player

I used ASPNetVideo:WindowsMedia to play  video in ASP.NET(c#)

```
 <ASPNetVideo:WindowsMedia ID="WindowsMedia1" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="400px">
 </ASPNetVideo:WindowsMedia>
```

This plays only .wmv files. I need to play mp4  and  other  video files also.

Please  anyone  help me  doing this.

Thanks  in advance

Comment: is it necessary we need to use the same control to play videos?

Answer (score 1):

Not a .NET solution but I highly recommend this:

[Media Element JS](http://mediaelementjs.com/)

This works all the way down to IE6 from what I've seen, it supports HTML5 until it isn't available and then falls back to flash if need be. And it supports mobile devices.

Sorry its a late reply, unfortunately wasn't on StackOverflow back then.